# fb conversion api through google tag manager

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager, tracking, google-tag-manager-server-side

i already setted up the facebook pixel and fb conversion api and google analytics through google tag manager on woocommerce
and all events fired correctly on google tag manager and sent to google analytics correctly
also when testing the events on facebook event manager all the browser events recieved correctly but the server side events only the page view and the product category recieved
content view , add to cart , checkout and purchase didn’t recieved toface book event manager
can any one help me fixing this

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, the GA4 client is responsible for processing the Facebook events for the CAPI. You have to create GA4 event tags with Facebook event parameters and send those to your server-side GTM.